# Error when training more than one step in Tensorflow: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, input

I'm trying to train a model that takes as input a narrow-band waveform and wide-band waveform. I've set up the batch pipeline for the nb_audio_batch and wb_audio_batch tensors. I notice that after the first step, TensorFlow starts complaining that nb_input and wb_input are NoneTypes. However, I added some print statements to see that they are in fact NumPy arrays with real values, even after the first step. Am I not supposed to call sess.run() twice in the same for loop or something? I would appreciate any help/advice!

```
# Train
for step in range(NUM_STEPS):
    start_time = time.time()

    # Get inputs
    nb_input, wb_input = sess.run([nb_audio_batch, wb_audio_batch])

    # Get outputs
    summary, loss_report, op = sess.run([summaries, reduced_loss, op], 
        feed_dict={x: nb_input, gt: wb_input})
```

Here is where I define nb_audio_batch and wb_audio_batch (defined earlier in the actual code):

```
# Create inputs
with tf.name_scope('create_inputs'):
    reader = AudioReader(NB_DATA_DIR,
                         WB_DATA_DIR,
                         coord,
                         sample_rate=SAMPLE_RATE,
                         sample_size=SAMPLE_SIZE,
                         silence_threshold=0.0)
    nb_audio_batch, wb_audio_batch = reader.dequeue(BATCH_SIZE)
    nb_audio_batch = mu_law_encode(nb_audio_batch, Q_LEVELS)
    wb_audio_batch = mu_law_encode(wb_audio_batch, Q_LEVELS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `sess.run()` as many times as you want. My guess (you should provide more details) is that the error is coming from the `nb_input, wb_input = sess.run([nb_audio_batch, wb_audio_batch])` line. TensorFlow needs you to specify `Tensors` or something that can be converted to a `Tensor` to fetch. It looks like either `nb_audio_batch` or `wb_audio_batch` is `None`.

You say that you added print statements to check that `nb_audio_batch` is a numpy array. That makes little sense. If they are already numpy arrays, then you know their numeric values. Why do you want tensorflow to compute them?

Also, your code is fairly strange, you do `sess.run()` to fetch some values and directly feed them back into another call to `sess.run()`. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but it is unnecessary and inefficient. You should be able to build one tensorflow graph that computes you final results (e.g. `loss_report`) in one go. It is inefficient, because tensorflow will need to copy the data for `nb_input` to a numpy array and then back to a tensor between the calls to `sess.run()`. This can be especially slow if you are using a GPU.